# Pass data from FormView to DetailView

Tags: django, django-views

I am attempting to include Celery in my project so that it asynchronously creates the `Hashtag` object. However, I need to check if the `Hashtag` object has been created yet by Celery. To do so, I have overridden `get()` in `SearchResultsView` with:

`if Hashtag.objects.filter(search_text=self.search_text).exists():`.

Specifically, I am unsure why `search_text=self.search_text` doesn't work? Perhaps, it's required that I override `get_context_data` in the `FormView` to pass the `search_filter` data to the `DetailView`? Alternatively, I should use `self.get_object()` in `get()` before using the `if` statement?

**Models.py**

```
class Hashtag(models.Model):
    search_text = models.CharField(max_length=140, primary_key=True)
```

**Views.py**

```
class HashtagSearch(FormView):
    model = Hashtag
    form_class = SearchHashtagForm

    def get_success_url(self, search_filter, **kwargs):
        return reverse('mapping_twitter:results', kwargs={'pk':search_filter})

    def form_valid(self, form):
        search_filter = self.get_tweets(form)
        iterate_tweets.delay(search_filter)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url(search_filter))

    def get_tweets(self, form):
        search_filter = self.request.POST.get('search_text').lower().lstrip("#")
        return search_filter


class SearchResultsView(DetailView):
    model = Hashtag
    template_name = 'mapping_twitter/results.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if Hashtag.objects.filter(search_text=self.search_text).exists():
             self.draw_histogram(request)
        return super(SearchResultsView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SearchResultsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

Answer (score 1):

I speculate the problem is something to do with your 'super'. Your 'get' is returning what SearchResultsView.get() inherited from DetailView.get(), but not then modifying the object with your specific additions. Maybe:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    s = super(SearchResultsView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)  
      #s is a [httpResponse][1] object
    if Hashtag.objects.filter(search_text=self.search_text).exists():
         s['hist'] = self.draw_histogram(request)
    return s
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#setting-header-fields

Comment: I'm not sure that's going to work because I don't know how a header 'hist' and associated html gets rendered from a httpresponse object - maybe they don't. I'd be more comfortable if this was modifying get_context_data.